# Python - declare method name in dictionary with method definition in outside class

Tags: python

```
from foo import fooClass

dict = {'a': method1, 'b': method2}

bar = fooClass()

method = dict['a']

bar.method()
```

I want to define a dictionary with a reference to a method but the method definition is not in the scope of the dictionary definition.

Currently, I get a NameError: name 'method1' is not defined.

To clarify, I have seen examples where functions are defined, then a dictionary using the function names is created in the same scope but this is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to point the dictionary to the actual method:

```
from foo import fooClass

dict = {'a': fooClass.method1, 'b': fooClass.method2}
```

Since `method1` *isn't* defined in that scope, you need to reference the method on the `fooClass` class.

---

Alternatively, if you didn't want to have to keep referening `fooClass` in your code, you could store the methods as strings and use `getattr()` do to this:

```
from foo import fooClass

dict = {'a': 'method1', 'b': 'method2'}

bar = fooClass()
method = getattr(bar.__class__, method = dict['a'])
bar.method()
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I considered defining an instance of the class but then I would have to pass it around and thought there has to be a better way. Perfect answer!

Comment: @user3089611 If it helped you can click the green tick to accept this answer to indicate to other users searching for answer, that you have an acceptable answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks, again. I have read on stackexchange for quite awhile now and I think this is my first post so thanks for the heads up.